# PLY Parsing error for function declaration

Tags: python, ply

I trying to parse the following source language in python

```
print("hello")
```

What i am doing in PLY is the following

```
import ply
import yacc

tokens =('LPAREN','RPAREN','STRING','PRINT')
reserved ={
('print': 'PRINT')
}

t_LPAREN ='\('
t_RPREN = '\)'
t_STRING = r'\".*?\"'

t_ignore = " \t"

def p_print(p):
  'statement : print LPAREN STRING RPAREN'
  print(p[3])
def p_error(p):
  print("Syntax error at %s"%p.value)
lex.lex()
yacc.yacc()
s ='print("Hello")'
yacc.parse(s)
```

I was expecting that it will print `Hello`. But i am getting the error

> Syntax err at 'print'

Anyone can help me what mistake i am doing?
Thanks

Comment: There are several errors in that excerpt that will prevent in from running (eg. the syntax error in the definition of `reserved`,  the misspelling of `t_RPREN` and the absence of an import of `lex`.) Please ensure that the code pasted into the question actually produces the error reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of everything that was off with your code:

1. Import statements. You've missed importing the modules properly. I'm not sure how you got as far as you did, but the right way to import these modules is with

   ```
   import ply.lex as lex
   import ply.yacc as yacc
   ```
2. the `PRINT` token is specified, but no rule defined for it. Define the rule like this:

   ```
   t_PRINT = r'print'
   ```
3. Your grammar rule for the print statement should specify the token name, not what the token matches too.

   ```
   def p_print(p):
     r'statement : PRINT LPAREN STRING RPAREN'
     ...
   ```
4. Removed the `reserved` structure, it seemed to serve no purpose.

After fixing these errors, we have:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

tokens =('LPAREN','RPAREN','STRING','PRINT')

t_LPAREN ='\('
t_RPAREN = '\)'
t_STRING = r'\".*?\"'
t_PRINT = r'print'
t_ignore = " \t"

def p_print(p):
  'statement : PRINT LPAREN STRING RPAREN'
  print(p[3])

def p_error(p):
  print("Syntax error at %s"%p.value)

lex.lex()
yacc.yacc()
s ='print("Hello")'
yacc.parse(s)
```

Output:

```
WARNING: No t_error rule is defined
"Hello"
```

It's okay for now, but do define a `t_error` rule for larger programs.